How to have @createdBy and @updatedBy annotation in prisma schema?
In a nestjs and prisma api, I would like to add audit columns to my database.
Writting the mapping to get the user.idin each create/update method of each of my entities is cumbursome. In spring data rest, this is how they do auditing:
  @CreatedBy
  private User user;

  @CreatedDate
  private DateTime createdDate;

In prisma for example, I can use @updatedAt annotation in my schema to have the updatedData columns without writing code.
I would like to have @createdBy and @updatedBy audit annotation, either in prisma or in my nestJS code to audit the connected user.id who made the creation or modification of a row.
How is this possible?

Prisma doesn't have the concept of a "user" that is native to it, so you need to add that yourself.
https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/prisma-schema-reference#attributes
You would need to create a User model in your Prisma schema and then add the relation to the corresponding models manually. If you make the field that points to the User required, you won't be able to create an instance of that model without also specifying the User.
model User {
  id        String   @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())

  createdDocuments      Document[] @relation(name: "DocumentsCreatedByUser")
  lastModifiedDocuments Document[] @relation(name: "DocumentsLastModifiedByUser")
}

model Document {
  id        String   @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())

  userCreatedBy         User @relation(fields: [userCreatedById], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, name: "DocumentsCreatedByUser")
  userCreatedById       String
  userLastModifiedBy    User? @relation(fields: [userLastModifiedById], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull, name: "DocumentsLastModifiedByUser")
  userLastModifiedById  String?
}


I want to have audit on my tables. Sorry if I was not clear. I managed to do it using a NestMiddleware that parse my JWT, save the id in a request context, then use that id in a custom prisma extension to automatically fill my createdById and updatedById columns. It work similarly than @createdAt / @updatedAt, except prisma doesn't support custom annotation, so I use the presence of those field to decide if the id must be set in my custom prisma extension

You can't add custom annotations to the Prisma schema itself. The closest you could get is Prisma extensions to augment specific models, but this is a manual process you'd have to do for every model. There's not a straightforward way of doing it for the entire schema.
